The pre-trained model stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-refiner-1.0 is not working on when giving input image
the issue is that when giving the input image to the stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-refiner-1.0 model then it is not taking the given image rather than that model is creating the image according to the prompt.
prompt = "make it anthropomorphic dog as a doctor"
so what I am expecting is that when giving the input image to the model then, it should that image and make according to the prompt.
